# here-document with bash -c

Tags: bash, 22.04

This example script:

```
cat <<- EOF | bash -c
    command1 args
    command2 args
    command3 args
    command4 args
    command5 args
EOF
```

Returns: `bash: -c: option requires an argument`
How do I use bash -c with here-document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't!

The `-c` is only for a script passed in as the first argument, not piped in via standard input as a heredoc does.

Instead you use `-s`, which can be omitted if there are no other arguments passed to the script.

---

Also, after replacing with `-s` you could also simplify:

```
cat <<- EOF | bash -s
```

to:

```
<<- EOF bash -s
```

Like most cats, the `cat` does nothing.

Comment: +1 for that last sentence :D

Comment: Is the more correct and elegant syntax `bash -s <<- EOF` or `<<- EOF bash -s`?

Comment: Either is fine.  I personally prefer putting `<` and `<<` before the command as it keeps the pipeline in order from left to right, though this is less common.